# Vue agile can't style agile actions/buttons

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, styling

I am trying to styling the buttons of vue-agile but nothing works.

My Jade/Pug looks as following:

```html
.carousel-wrapper
  client-only(placeholder="Loading...")
    VueAgile(:navButtons="true" :dots="true" :autoplay="false" slidesToShow="3")
      .slide
        img(:src="getImgUrl(product.name+'1', 'normal')" :alt="product.name")
      .slide
        img(:src="getImgUrl(product.name+'2', 'normal')" :alt="product.name")
      .slide
        img(:src="getImgUrl(product.name+'3', 'normal')" :alt="product.name")
```

I have tried the following selectors to style but not a single change was visible in each case i just tried to change the backgrouned-color to red.

```css
.agile {
  .agile__actions {
    button.agile__nav-button .agile__nav-button--prev {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}

.agile {
  &__dot {
    button {
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}

.agile {
  &__dot button{
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

And in each of these cases i also tried to add !important but it didn't make a difference.

I also tried adding custom templates to prevButton and nextButton like this:

```css
.carousel-button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
template(slot="prevButton" class="carousel-button")
```

Ofcourse this didn't work either the whole class `carousel-button` is lost in the process of rendering.

So my question is, how do i style the nextButton prevButton and the dots?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the elements once they've rendered using dev tools and see if there is any consistent class/id/html element that you can target with css?

Comment: yes thats how i got button.agile__nav-button .agile__nav-button--prev

Comment: If the selectors match but the rules still don't apply, you probably have `scoped` attribute set on your `<style>` tag. Wrap your SCSS inside `:deep(.carousel-wrapper ) { /* scss here */ }` and it will work. Alternatively, remove the `scoped` attribute. It's all in the [docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html).

Comment: Note `:deep(.a){.b{}}` is the new syntax. It used to be `.a /deep/ .b{}` or `.a >>> .b{}`. What would work in your case depends on which version of vue-loader you're using.

Comment: These selectors are way too complicated for my small brain so instead i just made custom elements and used the methods that came with vue-agile

Comment: What do you mean by _"I made custom elements"_? If it means you're using shadow DOM (and your components end in `.ce.vue`), that's why your style doesn't apply. Afaik, working with shadow DOM far exceeds any alternative in terms of overall complexity. But, then again, what do I know? Happy coding!

Comment: what i meant with custom elements i just i made my own divs and added click events that use vue-agile methods like `goToPrev()` etc.

I have no idea what shadow DOM is so i can't answer that question.